# Understanding FM Broadcast Receiver with RDA5807FP

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, radio, ham-radio

I've been trying to build an FM broadcast receiver for the last few weeks know, with simple designs like with LC circuits, but I've realized that an IC based radio outperforms simple transistor radios. I've started looking a round for cheap FM receiver chips, and I've found one that is used in many soldering kits, called the RDA5807FP. I found a [schematic online](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81mZ+5fLHrL.pdf) for the soldering kit, as pictured below. [image: radio]

I also looked at the [datasheet](https://opendevices.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/RDA5807FP.pdf), and it seems like it wouldn't work in the above configuration. By default, the chip is muted, and it seems like there is no way to change that, besides with I2C. I2C is volatile (I believe), so if they programmed it once with I2C and turned it off, everything would reset, and the chip would be muted again, leaving us with the same problem as before. The only way the datasheet says that it can interface is this: "Only support 2-wire bus interface", so (I believe) it is referring to the earlier-mentioned I2C. Even the example circuit in the datasheet is configured to work with I2C:

[image: more radios!]

So, my question is, how does this simple FM receiver work without a microcontroller? Is there something in the datasheet that I'm missing?

I'm also open to suggestions about different chips, along as it's simple, cheap, and still produced.

Thanks for all your help, and I apologize for my beginners ignorance.

Comment: You are not missing anything. This part is controlled by I2C. The volume is set to max at power up so maybe that's why it is in mute mode.

Comment: @Rodo If it is controlled by I2C, then how does the circuit that is used in simple soldering kits operate? That circuit isn't using the I2C interface, and in fact, it has buttons on the SCLK and SDA pins. Thanks for your help, BTW.

Comment: Seems a similar chip (FM 1310?) is self-contained, requiring no I2C - however, pinout appears different. Not to be confused with MC1310 stereo decoder chip. https://www.electrodragon.com/product/fm-radio-module-64-108mhz-wo-mcu/

Comment: It is curious that RDA5807FP data sheet shows pin #6 **GND**, while OP's schematic shows pin #6 **VDD**. The purpose of this pin is not documented. IMO a somewhat sketchy data sheet.

Comment: @Charlie Nicholson: Can u provide a link to this "simple soldering kits"?

Comment: @Rodo Here is the link to one of the many online retailers. I also included the link to instructions to build the kit in my main post. https://www.amazon.com/Icstation-76MHz-108MHz-Receiver-Electronic-Soldering/dp/B088827NL8/ref=sr_1_12_sspa?crid=U2O2ZDAFLPQS&keywords=fm+radio+soldering+kit&qid=1695461616&sprefix=fm+radio+soldering+kit%2Caps%2C115&sr=8-12-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9tdGY&psc=1.

Comment: @glen_geek That seems like an interesting chip. Unfortunately, when I looked into it, there are no vendors that still sell it.

Comment: @Charlie Nicholson: Where does it says the part number of the chip? I couldn't find it. Do you have that kit and is it the same part number? You may need to dig into the details of the datasheet to find out how they change frequency with a push button. But section "3.5 Control Interface" says: "The RDA5807FP only supports I2C control interface."

Comment: @Rodo Yes, I bought the kit, and it has the same part number as the schematic I found. The datasheet does not give enough information for me to understand how the GPIOs are configured, which are the pins the buttons are connected to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the RDA5870FP is a programmable FM Radio chip can be controlled in a simple way with push buttons when pin6 is held High. Then the GPIO pins 1,7,8,15,16 are then: power, ch-, ch+, vol-, vol+ and there is a datasheet, RDA7088, which refers to this configuration.
When pin 6 is held lo, then it can be controlled by i2c with rds and i2s output, which is shown in the RDA5870FP datasheet.